# AD Users Cannot Login Through GDM/LightDM

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, lightdm, winbind

I've setup Winbind & Kerberos on my CentOS 7 server to allow network users to login. The network users can login fine through SSH, but not through the display manager. I've experienced the same issue whether using LightDM or GDM.

Local users are able to login just fine. For the network users, when they login it will accept their password but kick them back to the login screen.

I have been scratching my head over this all day, tweaking pam settings to see if I can get it to work. I have also disabled SELinux and rebooted the server to rule out that possibility. Does anyone know what could be wrong here?

Here are the logs for a network user login:

System logs:

```
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local lightdm[10471]: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=mmoyles
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local lightdm[10471]: pam_krb5[10471]: TGT verified using key for 'host/iisfyblabetl001.incite.local@INCITE.LOCAL'
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local lightdm[10471]: pam_krb5[10471]: authentication succeeds for 'mmoyles' (mmoyles@INCITE.LOCAL)
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local lightdm[10471]: pam_winbind(lightdm:account): user 'mmoyles' granted access
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local lightdm[9639]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local systemd-logind[679]: New session 29 of user mmoyles.
-- Subject: A new session 29 has been created for user mmoyles
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
--
-- A new session with the ID 29 has been created for the user mmoyles.
--
-- The leading process of the session is 10471.
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local systemd[1]: Started Session 29 of user mmoyles.
-- Subject: Unit session-29.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-29.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local systemd[1]: Starting Session 29 of user mmoyles.
-- Subject: Unit session-29.scope has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-29.scope has begun starting up.
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local lightdm[10471]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user mmoyles by (uid=0)
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local lightdm[10471]: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user mmoyles
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local systemd-logind[679]: Removed session 29.
-- Subject: Session 29 has been terminated
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
--
-- A session with the ID 29 has been terminated.
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local lightdm[10517]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jul 03 16:15:01 iisfyblabetl001.incite.local systemd-logind[679]: New session c19 of user lightdm.
-- Subject: A new session c19 has been created for user lightdm
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
--
-- A new session with the ID c19 has been created for the user lightdm.
```

lightdm.log:

```
+1215.10s] DEBUG: Seat: Greeter stopped, running session
[+1215.10s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session6
[+1215.10s] DEBUG: Session pid=10471: Running command /etc/X11/xinit/Xsession mate-session
[+1215.10s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/mmoyles
[+1215.10s] DEBUG: Session pid=10471: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+1215.14s] DEBUG: Activating VT 1
[+1215.14s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session 29
[+1215.17s] DEBUG: Session pid=10471: Exited with return value 0
[+1215.17s] DEBUG: Seat: Session stopped
[+1215.17s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+1215.17s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 9627
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: Process 9627 exited with return value 0
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: X server stopped
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 1
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: Seat: Display server stopped
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: Seat: Active display server stopped, starting greeter
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating greeter session
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating display server of type x
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: Using VT 1
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting local X display on VT 1
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: Launching process 10509: /usr/bin/X -background none :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt1 -novtswitch
[+1215.24s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+1215.42s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 10509
[+1215.43s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Got signal from X server :0
[+1215.43s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+1215.43s] DEBUG: Seat: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+1215.43s] DEBUG: Session pid=10517: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+1215.44s] DEBUG: Session pid=10517: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+1215.44s] DEBUG: Seat: Session authenticated, running command
[+1215.44s] DEBUG: Session pid=10517: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
[+1215.44s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm
[+1215.44s] DEBUG: Session pid=10517: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+1215.44s] DEBUG: Activating VT 1
[+1215.44s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c19
[+1215.46s] DEBUG: Session pid=10517: Greeter connected version=1.10.6
[+1215.69s] DEBUG: Session pid=10517: Greeter start authentication
[+1215.69s] DEBUG: Session pid=10535: Started with service 'lightdm', username '(null)'
[+1215.70s] DEBUG: Session pid=10535: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+1215.70s] DEBUG: Session pid=10517: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+1215.73s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 changed
[+1215.74s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User11092 changed
[+1215.74s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1001 changed
```

pam.d/system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
#auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=KEYRING use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
#account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_krb5.so
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=KEYRING
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=KEYRING use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_krb5.so
session     optional      pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=KEYRING
```

pam.d/lightdm

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth     [success=done ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux_permit.so
auth       required    pam_env.so
auth       substack    system-auth
-auth       optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
-auth       optional    pam_kwallet5.so
-auth       optional    pam_kwallet.so
auth       include     postlogin
account    required    pam_nologin.so
account    include     system-auth
password   include     system-auth
session    optional    pam_selinux.so close
session    optional    pam_loginuid.so
session    optional    pam_console.so
-session    optional    pam_ck_connector.so
session    optional    pam_selinux.so open
session    optional    pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    optional    pam_namespace.so
-session    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
-session    optional    pam_kwallet5.so
-session    optional    pam_kwallet.so
session    include     system-auth
session    optional    pam_lastlog.so silent
session    include     postlogin
```

The .xsession-errors file in the network user's home directory is empty, and it does appear to create an .Xauthority file in the home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel dumb... After battling with this problem for 3 days, The reason was that I had a .profile in /etc/skel that was setting SHELL=/bin/bash so pam_mkhomedir was adding this file for new domain users but it wasn't on my local account.